# Bootstrap: Fill whole container under navbar minus navbar height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, size

On a page styled with Twitter Bootstrap and using the *navbar* I wanted to fill the whole container below the navigation bar with a Google Maps map. To accomplish that I have added the CSS following below.

I define for the `html` and `body` elements the sizes to 100% so that this is used for the map's size definition. This solution, however, yields one problem:

The map's height is now the same as the whole page height, which results in a scroll bar which I can scroll for the 40px the navigation bar adds. How can I set the size of the map to `100% - 40px` of the navigation bar?

```
#map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}

#map img {
        max-width: none;
}

html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}

.fill { 
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

For completeness the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
                <!-- Stylesheets -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/core.css">
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="navbar">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container fill">
                        <div id="map"> 
                        </div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could solve the problem with absolute positioning.

```css
.fill {
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/unbqR/)

You could also make the navbar `.navbar-fixed-top` and somehow add a padding or margin inside the `#map` element.

Comment: Am I right, that this way, the app isn't responsive anymore, as Bootstrap toggles its menu over the absolute positioned map div?

Comment: @JürgenZornig Responsiveness is not an absolute state. If this works for your layout on smaller/wider screens, then it's responsive. If not, throw in a couple of media queries and make it fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but if I position a Div absolute top 40px, standard bootstrap menu behaviour on smaller screens will overlap my div when I open the navbar menu. Sorry, I just wanted to find out of this answer fits my layout needs. Just solved it in another way (with Position:static)

Comment: @JürgenZornig can you share how you solved it with `position: static;`?

Comment: I forked Sherbrow's fiddle to create a demo that contains a map: http://jsfiddle.net/wrv369/hy14wepf/

Comment: I could use this responsively with bootstrap as the navbar had a fixed height (56px) across devices. All I did was set the .navbar z-index to 1 so that it expanded over the map