# Bootstrap, fullscreen site : scrollbar on a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a fullscreen website, and I would like to have a scrollable div to display text content ; here is my page : http://www.jeremy-dutheil.fr/barconniere/pages/enterprise

You can see that the scrollbar appears on the body, but this is not what I want ; I would like the scrollbar to appear only on the div content, and not on the body.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could use that : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11930307/1478467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this style in your global.css

Line 109 I think, change your style in your #enterprise #textContainer {}

Like so...

```
#enterprise #textContainer {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 height: 445px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 overflow: auto;
 padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 }
```

This code is just to show you how your div with your scrollbar will look like. You may further customize it according to your liking.

The style code above shall output a page similar to [BELOW IMAGE]. Look at that scrollbar, It's cute.[image: THIS ONE]

Comment: Yep but you fixed the height, that's not what I want :/ I need the container to be 100% height, but still with a scrollbar when the text overflows

Comment: Like I said before, you may customize it according to our liking. Then work on the HEIGHT.